# How to use an OR condition in my join for hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

How can the following SQL get represented in Hibernate?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN1 OR TABLE1.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN2 OR TABLE1.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN3
```

TABLE1 has a value that can exist in either COLUMN1, COLUMN2 or COLUMN3 of TABLE2.  I need this relationship because I'm embedding TABLE2 as an object in TABLE1's class.

E.g.,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="COLUMN1", referencedColumnName="COLUMN1"),
            @JoinColumn(name="COLUMN1", referencedColumnName="COLUMN2")
})
private TABLE2 object;
```

The above code does not work and throws the following error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns:

Comment: So do you need a way to make this into HQL? Or into entity objects? What exactly do you mean by represent?

Comment: Entity objects.  I mean how would embedding TABLE2 look like in hibernate.  I've modified my question to include more description of the class join.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I choose was to add TABLE2 as 3 separate objects by joining on the 3 different columns.  I also set optional = true to allow for a left outer join.  I wasn't crazy about this approach because it seems this should be done differently.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN1", referencedColumnName="COLUMN1")
private TABLE2 object1;

@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN1", referencedColumnName="COLUMN2")
private TABLE2 object2;

@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN1", referencedColumnName="COLUMN3")
private TABLE2 object3;
```